# Inconsistent operator overload resolution when using operators with "function style" syntax ('(binaryOp)(lhs, rhs)', and '(unaryOp)(operand)')

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, swift3

#### Question (/TL;DR)

In the details below we see that using function style (`(unaryOperator)(operand)`, `(binaryOperator)(lhsOperand, rhsOperand)`) syntax to call operator functions seemingly override the type checker's normal overload resolution rules; the the overload simply picks the first (in order of definition) overload that it can find.

- Is this a bug? Or is this some peculiar but expected behaviour of the call-operator-by-function-style (`(unaryOperator)(operand)`, `(binaryOperator)(lhsOperand, rhsOperand)`) syntax?

---

#### Background

I just read Matt Gallagher's excellent post on some current issues with the Swift type checker

- [Exponential time complexity in the Swift type checker](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/07/12/type-checker-issues.html)

One of the issues raised in the article is the problems that can follow from the fact that generic overloads are not considered in the overload resolution of *operators*, given that non-generic alternatives exist. Gallagher shows one such "issue" with the following example

```
/* note: Swift 3 */
prefix operator %% {}
prefix func %%(_ x: Float) -> Float { return x }
prefix func %%<I: Integer>(_ x: I) -> I { return x }

let y = %%1          // integer literal
print(y.dynamicType) // "Float"
```

We naturally see the same result if we switch places on the two `%%` operator definitions above, i.e.

```
/* ... same result as above */
prefix operator %% {}
prefix func %%<I: Integer>(_ x: I) -> I { return x }
prefix func %%(_ x: Float) -> Float { return x }
```

Note also that the above strictly non-generic precedence for overload resolution is not present for functions, as shown by Gallagher with the following example

```
/* resolves x to "Int", no matter the order 
   of these two function definitions */
func f(_ x: Float) -> Float { return x }
func f<I: Integer>(_ x: I) -> I { return x }

let x = f(1)
print(x.dynamicType) // "Int"
```

#### Further details pertaining the question

Now on to the peculiarity. We may call binary and unary operations in function style using the `(binaryOperator)(lhsOperand, rhsOperand)` and `(unaryOperator)(operand)` syntax, respectively. E.g.

```
let a = (+)(1, 2) // 3
let b = (-)(a)    // -3
```

Now, if we apply this syntax to the `%%` operator example above, the overload resolution rules as described above seems to no longer apply (no matter if we were to regard this as a function call or an operator call), as the type of `y` in the example above seemingly depends solely on the order in which the `%%` definitions appear.

```
prefix operator %% {}
prefix func %%(_ x: Float) -> Float { return x }
prefix func %%<I: Integer>(_ x: I) -> I { return x }

let y = (%%)(1)      
print(y.dynamicType) // "Float"

/* swap the order of the definitions ... */
prefix operator %% {}
prefix func %%<I: Integer>(_ x: I) -> I { return x }
prefix func %%(_ x: Float) -> Float { return x }    

let y = (%%)(1)      
print(y.dynamicType) // "Int"
```

We may even, *for some special conditions*<sup>†</sup>, introduce additional overloads that (expectedly) yields ambiguity for the normal `%%1` case, where the function style `(%%)(1)` case compiles without ambiguity, picking the first definition it can find.

```
prefix operator %% {}
prefix func %%(_ x: Double) -> Double { return x }  
prefix func %%<I: Integer>(_ x: I) -> I { return x }
prefix func %%(_ x: Float) -> Float { return x }    

// picks first %% definition it can find
let y = (%%)(1)   
print(y.dynamicType) // "Double"

// ambiguity error as expected
//let z = %%(1) // error: ambiguous use of operator '%%'
```

<sub>[†]: The non-error behaviour of this last example is really unreliable: if we e.g. introduce a 2nd generic overload, the snippet runs only without error if a non-generic overload is defined first, but moreover only if a generic overload definition follows that non-generic one. I wont dwell further, however, into that special-case madness, but it seems like some *"peek"* behaviour: accepting a first defined non-generic overload given that a peek of the next definition shows a generic one.</sub>

---

*(Tested for Swift 3.0 in the IBM Swift Sandbox. Swift 2.2 adapted version tested in XCode 7.3 playground as well as in a project)*