# Global variable visible before definition in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a piece of code which doesn't compile:

```
func find( n : String, m: Int)
{
    num = m
    name = n
}

var name : String = "A" 
var num : Int = 1

find( n: "1", m:  1)

print( name)
```

and it behaves as expected. But friends please tell me why the next piece of code works. The variable `name` is also defined after function and but this time it works ?

```
func find( n : String, m: Int)
{
//   num = m
   name = n
}

var name : String = "A" 
// var num : Int = 1

find( n: "1", m:  1)

print( name)
```

What's wrong with global variables definitions ?

Comment: Very probably this is a compiler bug because the behavior is not consistent.

Comment: It's *really* inconsistent. If you rearrange num and name, the error moves to name. If you put this in a Playground instead of an app, then you still get the error, but it runs anyway !?!?!. Yeah. This is a compiler bug. I'd post it to bugs.swift.org.

Comment: Just adding `()` after the body of `find(...)` seems to yield this invalid for any combination. Seems the compiler somehow peeks one single expression ahead of the function definition. (The same strange one-expression-ahead peek behaviour can be seen also for [non-related issues with operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445051)).

Answer (score 0):

This was a compiler bug in old Xcode versions. Works in current Xcode 12.3 (12C33) playground.